# How do I change from profile Compact 3 in IntelliJ IDEA for Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build.gradle, profile

I am trying to perform a gradle build on IntelliJ IDEA but when I try and build it I get an error saying “BufferedImage is not available in profile ‘Compact3’”.

Is there any way I can change the profile manually so that the build will work? I am very new to Java and am not entirely sure what’s going on, but I thought Compact3 had the most features out of the profiles, so if it’s not available in Compact3, where is it available?

Thanks for any help!

It’s taken me long enough to figure out how to get my syntax right, so this seems like an annoyingly minor hurdle to fall down at :(

Comment: `Compact3` is the biggest of [the compact profiles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/compactprofiles/compactprofiles.html), but still doesn't contain everything the "Full SE API" contains. If you want "more than compact3" then just remove any mention of profiles at all. I *think* that compact profiles were a feature that only ever existed **exactly** in Java 8, because in Java 9+ it was replaced with the way more general module system. (Slight correction: the JDK still supports profiles, but *only* when targeting Java 8)